# Cartesian Product of modules

Tags: ocaml

Trying to create a functor which would, given 2 modules of signature `Set.OrderedType`, create a module of signature `Set.OrderedType` representing objects of type the product of the two types, (Not really clear sorry) and being therefore able to compare said objects (using for instance the lexicographic order), to be able to use this module for `Set`

**But**, when I try to do this

```
module CartesianProduct2 (M1 : Set.OrderedType) (M2 : Set.OrderedType) :
  Set.OrderedType = struct
  type t = M1.t * M2.t

  let compare (a : t) (b : t) : int =
    match (a, b) with
    | (c, d), (e, f) ->
        if M1.compare c e <> 0 then M1.compare c e else M2.compare d f
end

(*A module to handle char*char *)
module Char2 = CartesianProduct2 (Char) (Char)
```

The code works fine except from the fact that OCaml does not recognize `Char2.t` as `char*char` :( meaning that when I try to compare two char*char instances like this:

```
Char2.compare ('a', 'b') ('c', 'd')
```

OCaml raises an error, saying: ***This expression has type 'a * 'b but an expression was expected of type Char2.t***

Comment: Does this have anything to do with abstract types or something?

Comment: Suggest rewriting `if M1.compare c e <> 0 then M1.compare c e else M2.compare d f` as `match M1.compare c e with 0 -> M2.compare d f | r -> r` or `let r = M1.compare c e in if r <> 0 then r else M2.compare d f` to avoid recomputing the comparison.

Comment: Also, you can more directly patten match: `let compare (c, d) (e, f) = let r = M1.compare c e in if r <> 0 then r else M2.compare d f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules in OCaml are structurally typed, so adding a module type annotation will only remove information. That is, by adding the return type annotation `Set.OrderedType` you force `t` to be abstract, hence the error.

The easiest way of fixing this is therefore to simply remove the annotation. The actual type will then be inferred. However, if you actually do need to remove some information from the module signature, you can also specify what the type of `t` should actually be using the `with type` construct:

```
module CartesianProduct2 (M1 : Set.OrderedType) (M2 : Set.OrderedType) :
  Set.OrderedType with type t = M1.t * M2.t = struct
  ...
end
```

Comment: To perhaps elaborate, a module can be used anywhere a module of type `Set.OrderedType` is expected as long as it has a type `t` and a `compare` function with the signature `t -> t -> int`. There is no need to explicitly say it implements that signature. However, doing this can be useful to generate a compiler error immediately in case you fail to implement that signature, rather than at the point where the module is used to try to instantiate a functor.